# Generated edit page loses reference to foreign key object ASP .Net 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

My Model "Race" has a link to the model "Event" that it is a part of, when generating the edit page for the race I removed the drop-down for eventId and replaced it with a hidden field as I don't want the user to be able to change the event the race is a part of. However, in my post function, my model state is invalid as the Event is null even though the event Id is valid, I understand why but how do I correctly link the ID in the hidden input back to the Event?

The HTML of the edit page is:

```
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Race.RaceId" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Race.EventId"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Race.RaceName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Race.RaceName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Race.RaceName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

My get function is

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Race = await _context.Races
            .Include(r => r.Event).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RaceId == id);

        if (Race == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

and my post function is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Attach(Race).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!RaceExists(Race.RaceId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

With the "Race" model having these fields

```
    public int RaceId { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Race Name")]
    public string RaceName { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; } = null!;
```

And the event model being

```
public partial class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        Entrants = new HashSet<Entrant>();
        Races = new HashSet<Race>();
    }

    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public int? InvoiceId {get; set;}

    [Display(Name ="Event Name")]
    public string EventName { get; set; } = null!;

    [Display(Name ="Event Date")]

    [DataType(DataType.Date) ,DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Entrant> Entrants { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Race> Races { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**
It appears that if I set

```
public virtual Event Event { get; set; } = null!;
```

in the race model to be nullable i.e.

```
public virtual Event? Event { get; set; };
```

it works correctly as it no longer validates the event on post but is this the correct way?

Comment: hello,can you show me your Event model?

Comment: I've updated the post with the event model, hope that helps